# What risks in manipulating a provided stream multiple times

Tags: c#

Given a stream by a user such that we expect them to manage the disposal of it through typical using

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    MyMethod(stream);
}
```

Is there any risk to copying back to the stream after working on it. Specifically we have a method that populates the data, but we have a conditional need to sort the data. So MyMethod is something like this:

```
void MyMethod(Stream stream, bool sort = false)
{
    //Stream is populated
    stream.Position = 0;

   if(sort)
   {
       Sort(stream);
   }
}

void Sort(Stream stream)
{
     using(var sortedStream = new MemoryStream)
     {
         //Sort per requirements into the new sorted local stream
         sortedStream.Position = 0;

         //Is this safe? Any risk of losing data or memory leak?
         sortedStream.CopyTo(stream);
     }
}
```

The thing to notice is we are populating the stream provided by the user and then sorting it into a local stream. Since the local stream is owned by the local method it is cleaned up but in converse we can NOT clean up the provided stream, but want to populate it with the local results.

To reiterate my question, is there anything wrong with this? Is there a risk of garbage data being in the stream or some other issue I am not thinking of?

Comment: As long as everything is in a single thread there is no issues.  If you have multiple threads then you need to perform some sort of synchronization to make sure you do not set the position back to zero when it is still being used.

Comment: This is why there are immutable types,  readonly collections, etc., which you can expose without having risk. By passing mutable object you are allowing to do anything with it, so yes, it *should* be ok. And don't worry, you will get an exception if you do something wrong.

Comment: @jdweng granted streams are by no means thread safe, nothing written here should have an issue as it is all localized. There is no way for a position to get swapped on the wrong thread. If there is a thread swap the context switch handles all local variables being registered properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) is an abstract class, and has a lot of different implementations. Not all streams can be written to, so in some cases the code may not work as expected, or could crash.

```
     sortedStream.Position = 0;
     sortedStream.CopyTo(stream);
```

You would need to check the [CanSeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CanWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canwrite(v=vs.110).aspx) properties beforehand:

```
if (sortedStream.CanSeek & stream.CanWrite)
{
     sortedStream.Position = 0;
     sortedStream.CopyTo(stream);
}
else
{
    // not supported
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether a given stream support moving the position around and re-writing data over itself is going to depend on the specific stream.  Some support it, and some don't.  Not all streams are allowed to change their position, not all are able to write, not all are able to overwrite existing data, and some are able to do all of those things.

A well behaved stream shouldn't leak resources if you do any of those unsupported things; it *ought* to just throw an exception, but of course technically a custom stream could do whatever it wants, so you most certainly *could* write your own stream that leaks resources when changing the position.  But of course at that point the bug of leaking a resource is in that stream's implementation, not in your code that sorts the data in the stream.  The code you've shown here only needs to worry about a stream throwing an exception if an unsupported operation is performed.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you don't sort it before you insert it into the stream or why you use a stream at all when you access seems to be random-access, but technically, it's fine. You can do it. It will work.

Comment: The reason it is not sorted is due to expense. The user of the system may not care for the data to be sorted. The data is not random access but is held by an an object that has the "MyMethod" on it. Rather than cluttering my question with all of these details I deduced it down to the core questions we are having.